# Setting Full Width to WPF Image in C#

Tags: c#, wpf, resize

I'm trying to reduce my window size to 70%, in which there will be an image that will be stretched for 100% width and 30% (below the image) height, in which there is a stack panel containing some controls.

```
<Window x:Class="CapManageR.Video"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="Video" Height="500" Width="1000"
    Loaded="Window_Loaded"  Closing="Window_Closing">

  <Grid Name="grid1">

    <Image Source="c://a.png"   HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Height="700"></Image>
    <StackPanel Height="300" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
      <Slider x:Name="horizSlider" 
                Minimum="0"
                Maximum="100"
                Value="50"
                LargeChange="10"
                SmallChange="1"
                Width="200"
                Margin="186,356,406,51"
                PreviewMouseUp="horizSlider_PreviewMouseUp"/>
    </StackPanel>

  </Grid>

</Window>
```

I don't really know how to solve this. The above is my code so far. It is not really working. Can someone help so it will be proportional even upon resizing?

Comment: Define "not really working"

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen its just not showing it as i wanted... did u understand how i wish i to look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<Grid Name="grid1">
   <Grid.RowDefinitions>
     <RowDefinition Height="70*" />
     <RowDefinition Height="30*" />
   </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Image Grid.Row="0" Source="c://a.png" Stretch="Fill" />

    <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" >
       ....
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

Comment: thanks man but just one last question-if i want the controls im going to put in the stackpanel to  gradually incerase on the resize?(i mean like responsive haha)

Comment: allright.. so what would u suggest to me to use instead?